# Encryption/decryption of cookies by HAProxy

Tags: cookies, encryption, nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

We're trying to set up a load balancer with HAProxy which will serve multiple backend web applications. The use case is something like this:

- User browses to foo.com/app1
- HAProxy sees that the cookie doesn't contain session information, and redirects to an authentication gateway (a single-sign-on page of sorts)
- The auth gateway provides a form, where if the user successfully logs in, the gateway redirects back to HAProxy, with a COOKIE storing the session details
- HAProxy now sees that valid session information is present and redirects to app1-internal.foo.com (the actual web application) with the same COOKIE - which is used further by the web application.

Our doubt is in the 3rd step. We would like to encrypt the cookie which the authentication gateway adds (via AES or similar). The problem is, that at the HAProxy end we can't seem to figure out how to decrypt it, since HAProxy doesn't seem to support decrypting headers (or even running an external C/C++ program that can decrypt it). So our questions are:

1. Can we decrypt AES encrypted headers at HAProxy itself (note that this is not an SSL connection) ?
2. Is HAProxy not really designed for this use case - is there a better tool for this purpose that you can suggest for us?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: For folks trying to see this, we solved this by doing it via nginx and a custom module that decrypts the session cookie. https://www.airpair.com/nginx/extending-nginx-tutorial is a great start!